# Запуск gradle ошибка java_home

Tags: gradle

Пишу  "gradle" в cmd он работает, пишу "gradle" в bash  java error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory, но "java -version" работает в обеих

Comment: Что выдаёт echo $JAVA_HOME?

Comment: уже установил, ок-cя путь неправильный был